# ordinality position returns NULL. How to handle this

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

```
select pos
from users 
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(user_details->'userProfile') with ordinality arr(elem,pos)
where elem->>'userType'='employee' 
  and elem->>'userState'='onboarding pending'
```

In the above SQL, if I remove "and elem->>'userState'='onboarding pending'" then the query returns a "pos" value. However, when I run the above query (with the 'onboard pending') condition, it return NULL.

I need to do something if it returns null. How do I handle this?

I have tried coalesce/CASE , padding string before and after, and many other hacks but nothing is working.

Comment: How are you using the query? It won't return `NULL`, it will at best return an empty set of rows.

Comment: Could you add some sample data please that reproduces this? Ideally in a format ready to paste into https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Comment: I can't reproduce, and just don't believe you that happens at all.  I can believe it returns zero rows, but that is different than returning a single row of NULL.  If you select `*` rather than `pos`, what do you get?

Comment: Yes, it returns 0 rows. I stated incorrectly. Apologies. How do I handle it? if it returns no rows, then my update should not happen.  I receive this error "SQL Error [22004]: ERROR: path element at position 2 is null"

Comment: What path element? What update?